# pass javascript variable to ruby on rails controller to send in api further

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, google-maps-api-3, uber-api

I am having a google api map as index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
  // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
  // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
  // locate you.

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 15
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }



    </script>
    <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api   /js?key=AIzaSyBNvjq57_K8vPYRKETMN6bDogqCpRvBoA0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to use the var=pos in ruby on rails controller i.e products controller

```
require 'rubygems'

    require 'httparty'

    class ProductsController < ApplicationController



def index

    @results = HTTParty.get("https://api.uber.com          /v1/products?server_token=xyz&latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823").parsed_response

   respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@results) }
   format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
   end
   end
   end
```

and then pass seperate latitude and longitude in the api url so that it can take any latitude and longitude instead of giving it manually. 
How can I do it ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that the code in your controller runs on your server while the javascript runs in the client? The only way to "pass the variable to your controller" is to make another request to the server.

Answer (score 2):

As @max said, you have to make another request to a controller. If you use jQuery and want to make an AJAX request, it can be done like so:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "products/some_action",
  data: { lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Done" );
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

and in your `ProductsController` add:

```
def some_action
  # do something with params[:lat] and params[:lng]
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @pmicha but it did not help me as ajax request was not working .

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem asked above by passing params in windows.open javascript function and fetching that params in products controller

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
  // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
  // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
  // locate you.

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 15
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
          if(pos){
          window.open("/products?lat="+pos.lat+"&long="+pos.lng,"_blank")
        }
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }



    </script>
    <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api   /js?key=AIzaSyBNvjq57_K8vPYRKETMN6bDogqCpRvBoA0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

products controller:

```
require 'rubygems'

    require 'httparty'

    class ProductsController < ApplicationController



def index
    lat = params[:lat].to_s
    long = params[:long].to_s
    @results = HTTParty.get("https://api.uber.com/v1/products?server_token=your_server_token&latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+long).parsed_response


   respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@results) }
   format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
   end
   end
   end
```